# .Net port of the Wix standard bootstrapper application

Tags: wix

We are currently using WiX with the standard bootstrapper application. In the past this has worked well for our needs, however now we would like to add some additional functionality, such as validation of database details entered in the bootstrapper UI.

I know that this would be possible by modifying the standard bootstrapper application, however this requires coding in C which I would like to avoid. (I can write in C, but I'm far more competent and less error prone in .Net)

Is there a .Net port of the standard bootstrapper application so that we can implement these actions in .Net code, or would I need to write a .Net bootstrapper from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

No, WixStandardBootstrapperApplication is only available in native code. The BA for WiX itself is open source like the rest of WiX: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/Setup/WixBA

Comment: I considered using the installer for WiX itself, but its a fairly unconventional UI.  Its good as a reference for how to implement a bootstrapper in .Net but its not a particularly good starting point for customization.